# Win2008 perfmon data collector set doesn't start?

Tags: windows-server-2008, perfmon

I'm trying to monitor my Windows 2008 R1 performance using perfmon, however, after creating a new data collection set in perfmon, it won't start at all.

Comment: What happens when you right-click and select start?

Comment: Simply nothing. nothing at all, not even an error message!